# Camera Effect in android application

Tags: java, android, colors, camera

I'm working on small android camera application that opens CameraPreview on start. I tryed to set a lot of ColorEffects to my Camera instance, but it doesn't work. There is my code where I use
setColorEffect method:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

UPD: I tryed to run my app on android 2.3.6 and color effects work on it. It doesn`t work on android 5.0

Please help me.

Comment: So I use Nexus 7 device with Android 5.0

Comment: It throws any exception?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the application compile? Does the camera do anything at all? Is it just the effects not being applied? Does it crash when you try to apply the filters? Does it not store the result? If you could clarify and add your uses-permissions that'd be great.

Comment: @Salmaan no, it doesn`t throw any exceptions

Comment: @user3427079 application work correctly, but just the effects doesn`t work. No crashes. I can store result in memory. I added permissions to main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This class was deprecated in API level 21.
>   We recommend using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.

Turns out Camera.Parameters is deprecated.

[Android Developer - Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)

You should use this instead for devices with API level > 21:

[Android Developer - android.hardware.camera2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

Comment: Is camera2 in the support libraries yet? I can't seem to find anything about it. Any ETA on when it will be added? The current camera is so awful to work with.

Comment: I dont know my friend :/